# how to build a "toggle switch" with bootstrap group buttons ? one is on the other is off and vice-versa

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I need two buttons (the buttons are used for changing between two collapsible divs) which are by default off and if one of them is switched on the other (if previously on) will switch off. I am using current version of bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js plus my JavaScript file in which I've written:

```
 $('#1kgbtn').on('click', function () {
 $('#25kgpack').collapse('hide')
 if ($('#25kgbtn').button('active') == true) {
   $('#25kgbtn').button('toggle')
 }
 else {}
 })
 $('#25kgbtn').on('click', function () {
 $('#1kgpack').collapse('hide')
 if ($('#1kgbtn').button('active') == true) {
   $('#1kgbtn').button('toggle')
 }
 else {}
 })
```

and my html code looks like this:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
 <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="1kgbtn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#1kgpack" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
  1kg package
</button>

<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="25kgbtn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#25kgpack" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
  2.5kg package
</button>
</div>
```

but the JavaScript I've written does not work correctly, only the collapsing part works, the button switching does not.

(I don't want to use radio, because that does not work with collapsing, well not for me at least)

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you want to just toggle the buttons kind of like radio buttons without the use of radio buttons.

You can set this code below the bootstrap script to cancel any defaults in the file after it has been read.  Html is read from the top down so your file would look something like this.

Using your code I added the class "remove-active" to both buttons and the removeClass to the javascript you had.  You was doing it right, you just need to trump bootstraps default actions. The default being that once toggled the need to be retoggled to leave active state.

```
   <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
     <button class="btn btn-outline-primary remove-active" id="1kgbtn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#1kgpack" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
      1kg package
    </button>

    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary remove-active" id="25kgbtn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#25kgpack" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
      2.5kg package
    </button>
</div>

 <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
$('#1kgbtn').on('click', function () {


        $('#25kgpack').collapse('hide')

        $('.remove-active').removeClass('active');

        if ($('#25kgbtn').button('active') == true) {
            $('#1kgbtn').button('toggle');
        }       
 });

 $('#25kgbtn').on('click', function () {

        $('#1kgpack').collapse('hide');
     $('.remove-active').removeClass('active');

     if ($('#1kgbtn').button('active') == true) {
         $('#25kgbtn').button('toggle');
    }
});
</script>
```

Using the data target you could get the id and do different things with it later. (this part is just cause its cool)

```
    $('button[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(){
    //log the id of the target
    console.log($(this).attr('data-target'));        
});
```

I hope this helps.

--edit--

I've modified the code a bit but made comments to help with the explanation.

```
            //on button click

        $('button').click(function(e){
            //the current button is toggled

            //check to see if the other button is toggled

            if($('.remove-active').hasClass('active')){ //if it has class this means it is active
                //store the active id
                var e = $('.remove-active.active').attr('id');

                //we clicked on the same button then we would equal the same id
                    if(e == $(this).attr('id')){
                        //collapse the clicked Id if we are unpressing the button
                        $(this).collapse('hide');

                        console.log(e + ' auto toggles with bootstrap and collapse the currently clicked target ' + $(this).attr('data-target'));                       

                       }else{ // else
                           //we untoggle the other button and element
                           $('#' + e).button('toggle');
                           //we also collapse the other element
                           $($('#' + e).attr('data-target')).collapse('hide');

                           console.log("The other element was clicked and we cleared it along with collapsing the " + $('#' + e).attr('data-target'));
                       }                        
               }

            //be sure to close out the console.log() stuff
            //this is just for viewing example
        });
```

This will toggle the current button, check if the other button is toggled and if so toggle it. Also if the button is toggled, then on click of that button, said button is then untoggled.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying a lot of things, but this solved it right away! Again – Thank you! :) although one of the buttons stays active afterwards even if I close the collapsable div, is there any solution to that ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing `data-toggle` attribute and managing toggle with Javascript. Each button calls `toggleBtnActiveState` function and passes two parameters to it: 
1) ID of the clicked button. 
2) ID of the hidden div

```
<button type="button" 
        id="dvdBtn"
        name="dvdBtn"  
        class="extra-attrib-btn btn btn-outline-info btn-default mx-1"
        onclick="toggleBtnActiveState('dvdBtn', 'dvdInput')">
  DVD
</button>

<button type="button" 
        id="bookBtn"
        name="bookBtn" 
        class="extra-attrib-btn btn btn-outline-info btn-default mx-1"
        onclick="toggleBtnActiveState('bookBtn', 'bookInput')">
  Book
</button>

<button type="button" 
        id="furnitureBtn"
        name="furnitureBtn" 
        class="extra-attrib-btn btn btn-outline-info btn-default mx-1"
        onclick="toggleBtnActiveState('furnitureBtn', 'furnitureInput')">
 Furniture
</button>
```

Javascript function works as follows:

```
function toggleBtnActiveState(buttonId, divId)
{
    activeButton = document.getElementById(buttonId);

    hiddenDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden-div');
    btns = document.querySelectorAll('.extra-attrib-btn');

    //Remove .active class for each btn
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(btns, function(btn)
    {
        removeClass(btn, 'active');
    })

    //Collapsable div show/hide logic
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(hiddenDivs, function(div) 
    {

        //If hidden div matches selected btn and is visible, hide it and selected btn active class
        if (div.id == divId && hasClass(div, 'show')) {
            removeClass(div, 'show');
            removeClass(activeButton, 'active');
            return;
        }
        // If it matches but is not visible, show it and btn active class
        if (div.id == divId && !hasClass(div, 'show'))
        {
            addClass(div, 'show');
            addClass(activeButton, 'active')
            return;
        }

        //This gets called if previous two statements are not, and removes visibility of the div
        if (hasClass(div, 'show')) {
            removeClass(div, 'show');

        }
    })
}
```

Helper classes:

```
function hasClass(el, className) {
    if (el.classList)
        return el.classList.contains(className)
    else
        return !!el.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)'))
}

function addClass(el, className) {
    if (el.classList)
        el.classList.add(className)
    else if (!hasClass(el, className)) el.className += " " + className
}

function removeClass(el, className) {
    if (el.classList)
        el.classList.remove(className)
    else if (hasClass(el, className)) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)')
        el.className = el.className.replace(reg, ' ')
    }
}
```